# Flash Media Server live streaming with multiple video files

Tags: streaming, media, live, flash-media-server

I am using Flash Media server 4.5 and i read the tutorial if i want to stream the live feed, i may need to use the media live encoder. but what i found in media encoder is i have to manually setup everything and it only support camera devices.

But in my case i have multiple video files keep received from another program, my goal is use the Flash Media server to perform a live boardcasting with these video file one by one.
That means when client watching the streaming, they will not notice the server is play mov1, then mov2, then mov4, then mov5... and so on.

Also can FMS dynamically create a new streaming session (invoke by code), so that when client A uploading some video files to the server, the FMS open a new streaming session only stream cilent A video files?

Can FMS achieve such purposes? any tutorial provided would be very helpful!

#### Edit for Open Bounty

I want to basically deliver a live stream of video where a list of videos are source. I am currently using Flash Media Server with Cloudfront CDN to deliver content. So if I have video1, video2, and video3. I want to play them back to back as a live stream (so no skipping ahead in video), is it possible to do this? Bounty goes to clever workaround. Think of this as a television channel.

Comment: I'm also looking for similar solution. Did u find one?

Answer (score 0):

i have been working on the live streaming technologies for the past 1and half year . There is no option in flash live encoder for any file encoding.

1.To encoder your file you can use your dvd player devices or  some thing else which supports usb devices playback options.and use the dvd player output to broadcast using flash media live encoder. 
2.And the another set is to setup windows media encoder that supports file encoding(no need od dvd player) but it supports only windows media services.

At present i live webcast video file in this way only for my company http://www.malar.tv/live.php